# Created a carousel but errors if there is more than one. (fiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rgbjoy/q9VGh/

I want to have multiple carousels on one page, but don't want to effect them all. How do I go about this?

HTML:

```
<div class="project">
    <div class="prev">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="next">&nbsp;</div>
    <ul class="detail">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
// Slider
$('.detail li:first').before($('.detail li:last'));

$('.next').click(function() {
    var itemWidth = $('.detail li').outerWidth() + 10;
    var leftIndent = parseInt($(".detail").css("left"), 10) - itemWidth;
    $('.detail').animate({
        'left': leftIndent
    }, 400, function() {
        $('.detail li:last').after($('.detail li:first'));
        $('.detail').css({
            'left': '-200px'
        });
    });
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var itemWidth = $('.detail li').outerWidth() + 10;
    var leftIndent = parseInt($('.detail').css('left'), 10) + itemWidth;
    $('.detail').animate({
        'left': leftIndent
    }, 400, function() {
        $('.detail li:first').before($('.detail li:last'));
        $('.detail').css({
            'left': '-200px'
        });
    });
});
```

-- Extra --

How do I go about having all of the li items dimmed out and the one furthest to the left not?

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing things like this:

```
var itemWidth = $('.detail li').outerWidth() + 10;
```

The `$('.detail li')` will find all `<li>` elements within elements with a class of `detail`. All you need to do is restrict your search to the children of the appropriate `.project` and you can do that by going up the DOM to find your `.project` using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and coming back down using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var itemWidth = $(this).closest('.project').find('.detail li').outerWidth() + 10;
```

Similarly, `$(".detail")` becomes `$(this).closest('.project').find('.detail')` and so on.

Comment: I've never used closest. very interesting, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: The first line has the last li go before the first, so you can slide infinitely initially. How would you iterate through each class like you said?

Comment: @Tom: I'm not sure what you mean.